# PHP search form not getting results

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database with the name Harry Butler in it under the columns first_name and last_name with this code :

```
<?PHP

//Create the connection…
//("where the database is", 'Database login' , 'database password' , "Database name")
$con=mysqli_connect("", 'root', 'root', "Social");

//Check our connection…
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
    echo " Sorry Mate";
}
$fname = $_POST[fname];
$lname = $_POST[lname];


$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `User_info` WHERE first_name = '$fname' AND last_name = '$lname'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo $row['first_name'];
}


?>
```

Which gets the form data from the previous page :

```
<form action="searching.php" method="post">
<input id="fname" align="center" placeholder="First Name" name="fname"></input> 
<input id="lname" align="center" placeholder="Last Name" name="lname"></input>
    <select id="gender">
        <option value="Male">Male</option>
    <option value="Female">Female</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
    <option value="God">God</option>
    </select>
    <br />
</form>
```

Yet when the results are submitted i get nothing any ideas?

Comment: `echo $result;` run it in phpmyadmin or the command line

Comment: what's the value of $fname and $lname in searching.php?

Comment: Add mysqli_error() to the query and check any errors are throwing.

Answer (score 1):

change

```
$fname = $_POST[fname];
$lname = $_POST[lname];
```

to this:

```
$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
```

$_POST is associative array,so i hope it helped

Comment: while they should be quoted, they don't have to be.

Comment: still best practice to do it: http://de.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.foo-bar